# modeling polymorphism in UML - dependency to abstract classes

Tags: java, polymorphism, uml, abstract-class

I have searched many hours over the course of the last few semesters trying to make sure that I am presenting this correctly to my students. Nothing I have found shows this particular relationship. This semester I'd like KNOW that I'm doing it correctly.

We have an abstract class, Player and two concrete classes that extend it (Pitcher and PositionPlayer).  Then we have a class, Team with a map declared to be

> ```
>     <Integer, Player>
> ```

To me it seems that Team is dependent on Player (the abstract class) but I suppose dependence could be shown for the subclasses.  Please tell me which of these is correct, the top one or the bottom one? (my UML editor won't do italics, hence the tags). Thank you in advance for your help.

[image]

Comment: Don't know why you deleted your comment. I managed to see it so I will respond. If `Team` needs to downcast `Player` to `Pitcher` then yes the bottom part is good. What I'm saying is that this is bad design see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Downcasting#Criticism there are some useful links at the bottom of that page.

Comment: Somewhat relevant is [this](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/search?q=uml).  (And, of course, it sounds like that entire site could be relevant for you in any case.)

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct. The top is more general and the bottom one more specific. But both tell the same.

The following is to show where you would use the lower part of your design. If you have a third `Player` subclass which `Team` does not dependent on you use the lower representation - without a dependency to the new subclass.

[image]

Might not be very realistic, but that could be some fictive game constellation.

Comment: Thank you!  I really appreciate your time.  Also nice to know I haven't steered anyone wrong in the way  I've taught it.

Comment: How does `Team` depend on classes it doesn't use and knows nothing about? Even if it's correct UML (gonna trust you on that) this is not a sensible way to convey meaningful relationship, nobody should do that @AApplin and the standard should be changed.

Comment: @Oleg The `Joker` is just a `Player`. Not part of the `Team` but in the (not shown) complete domain he might play another role. Only just as a `Player`, not as team-player.

Comment: @Oleg I might have misunderstood. The `Team` is shown just with its name, not with anything inside. So it might carry a `Player` list. The above is just for brevity. Also (just noticed) the `Player` should be shown in italics as being abstract.

Comment: @ThomasKilian It's shown with a map of players. If there is such a thing as `TeamPlayer` and just `Player` can't be part of `Team` then the whole design should be different. With the current OP's design `Team` should only care about the `Player` class.

Comment: @Oleg This is not meant to be compliant with the OP's design but to show how his designs WOULD differ.

Comment: @ThomasKilian They don't differ OP asks about the correct way to represent a `Team` with a `map` of `Player`. Making `Team` dependent on subclasses of `Player` breaks OOP principles. Designing it in such a way that `Joker` subclass of `Player` can't be used by  `Team` is even worse.

Comment: @ThomasKilian Not sure it's my fault, I got it now. Still the bottom one shouldn't exist, if this information is important a redesign is in order.

Comment: @Oleg As said: fictive. But definitely it may exist in our universe. Just don't know in which domain. Imagine the Joker running on the field and being a Player. He IS one right then. The Team probably won't like it. But that's not under discussion. Just forget this being a real baseball game (whose rules I don't know anyway).

Comment: @ThomasKilian Nice story. And what a developer is supposed to do with it? I can't fathom any other(good) answer then add `TeamPlayer` to the hierarchy.

Answer (score -1):

If Team contains an attribute of type MAP, for me, it means that Team contains a list of player, each one identified by an id.

If Team contains an attribute of type Player with a cardinality 0..n, it means, that Team is associated with Player.

Since each Player is identified by an integer, for me, this is a qualified association.

[image]

Comment: apologize, the cardinality of Player should be one, for one id, there is one player.

Comment: If this is an answer please edit it in a way that will actually make it clear. If this is a question please ask another question.

Comment: this is the answer of the question in fact, for me a depency is not the right answer since it is an association ... I prefer to write the answer as a question, for me this is more kind.

Comment: So I rewrite my answer, the previous way of writng was more open and more kind, but if you prefer this way : I do not mind.

Comment: Much better, thanks. It can be open and kind, that's up to you(though other people might not like it and downvote or edit it out). With your original version I wasn't sure if it's an answer or a question and considered flagging it, that's not good.

Comment: and so ? I would be interested to know why someone set minus one and maybe can he argue for that to understand his mind ...